# insulation material condition

Tags: insulation, basement-insulation

Recently I needed to replace a drywall sheet in my garage, the wall is between garage and basement, so it is insulated. However I found that the insulation material got black down to the floor, I wonder if it is normal or material needs to be replaced?

[image]

Comment: Does that floor get damp or wet?  It does look like some kind of moud there.  Would need testing to tell if that is moud.

Comment: Possible water leak

Comment: @crip659 and Ruskes yes indeed there was a leak, so the black spot is likely a mould?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mold or mildew.

If you've fixed the leak, don a mask, cut out and discard the affected insulation, clean and/or treat the wood to remove and kill remaining mold or mildew, and place new insulation. You don't have to remove all the insulation, just the part that's infested (cut maybe 6"/150mm above the last black parts you see, making a nice straight cut so the new insulation can be easily cut to fit the old.)

Comment: Eye protection would not hurt either.